# SAS - defining variable as column sum and bootstrapping

Tags: sas, statistics-bootstrap

I have a chunk to bootstrap a dataset.

```
%let iter = 2;
%let seed = 777;

data work.seg;
    input segment $3. prem loss;
    datalines;
AAA 5000 0
AAA 3000 12584
AAA 200 245
AAA 500 678
;

data work.test;
    do i=1 to &iter;
        sumprem=0;

        do _n_=1 to 1000000 until (sumprem>=8700);
            row_i=int(ranuni(&seed)*n)+1;
            set work.seg point=row_i nobs=n;
            sumprem + prem;
            output;
        end;
    end;

    stop;
run;
```

It works, but I have a few questions.

1. How can I make the 400 number dynamic... I want `(sumprem >= 8700)` to be `(sumprem >= &threshold)` where `&threshold` is the sum of the `prem` column.
2. Is it correct how I am passing the `&seed`? Or should `(&seed)` be replaced with something like `(&seed + _n_)`?
3. How can I make the last data step into a macro... something like below, but I haven't gotten anything to work.

   ```
   %macro boot(data, iter, seed);

       %do i=1 %to &iter;

       sumprem=0;

       %do _n_=1 %to 1000000 %until (sumprem>=8700);
           row_i=int(ranuni(&seed)*n)+1;
           set work.seg point=row_i nobs=n;
           sumprem + prem;
           output;
       %end;
   %end;

   %mend;
   ```

Comment: There's no 400 in your code. Instead of passing the seed that way I think I prefer using CALL STREAMINIT().  Is there a reason you're using a data step to sum instead of a PROC. I know DoW loops can be efficient, but I didn't think they were faster than the PROCS.

Comment: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/183-2007.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to calculate the sum of prem from work.seq?

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select sum(prem) format=best32. into :threshold trimmed from seg ;
quit;
```

Your macro code is confusing macro logic, which can be used to generate code, and data step logic which is what operates on the actual data.  To make it into a macro just use the same macro variable names for the names of the parameters to the macro and leave the code the same.

```
%macro boot(in,out, iter, seed);
data &out;
  do until (eof);
    set &in end=eof;
    threshold + prem ;
  end;
  do i=1 to &iter;
    sumprem=0;
    do _n_=1 to 1000000 until (sumprem>=threshold);
      row_i=int(ranuni(&seed)*n)+1;
      set &in point=row_i nobs=n;
      sumprem + prem;
      output;
    end;
  end;
  stop;
run;
%mend boot;
```